# How do I make a DRY template in dustjs that may or may not use a base template?

Tags: templates, dust.js

I got this template:

```
{?doesExtend}
    {>base_template/}
    {<param}
        <div id='abc'>{foo}</div>
        <div id='def'>{bar}</div>
        <div id='ghi'>{bas}</div>
    {/param}
{:else}
    <div id='abc'>{foo}</div>
    <div id='def'>{bar}</div>
    <div id='ghi'>{bas}</div>
{/doesExtend}
```

This works but it's not DRY...I have to put the HTML in twice. How can I make it so that if doesExtend exists, then it will extend the template to a base template, and if it doesn't exist, then it will simply not extend it and render it as is, in a way that is DRY?

Answer (score 1):

I would just move the repeated code into a separate partial.

```
{! "div_template"  !}
<div id='abc'>{foo}</div>
<div id='def'>{bar}</div>
<div id='ghi'>{bas}</div>
```

Then your original template would look like:

```
{?doesExtend}
    {>base_template/}
    {<param}
        {>div_template/}
    {/param}
{:else}
        {>div_template/}
{/doesExtend}
```

Comment: Good answer...I would prefer though if I wouldn't even have to repeat `{>div_template/}`. Shouldn't I be able to just put a conditional for whether or not it should extend? Not even a conditional, but just have it extend if a certain parameter in my context object exists and not extend if it doesn't. If this can't be done, they should put this in.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example of what the template would look like if your desired feature were implemented?